# Where are the docs about dataclass fields that have no type hints?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Consider this example of dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Example:
    typed: str = "a"
    nontyped = "nt_value"  

# Now let's make some tests and see 'nontyped' behaviour

ex = Example()
ex2 = Example()

print(ex)
# Example(typed='a')

print(ex.nontyped)
# nt_value

print(asdict(ex))
# {'typed': 'a'}

ex.nontyped = 'new_value'
print(ex.nontyped)
# new_value

print(ex2.nontyped)
# nt_value

print(asdict(ex))
# {'typed': 'a'}

print(asdict(ex2))
# {'typed': 'a'}
```

I see that `nontyped` is a class attribute and it doesn't appear in the representation of the dataclass object.

Where can I read about this in the docs?

Comment: ...on [the `dataclasses` page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). _" A `field` is defined as a class variable **that has a type annotation**."_ There's no such thing as a field without a type hint - it's a class attribute because that's what happens _by default_ in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is an answer! Somehow I missed this sentence in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

All dataclass fields have a type annotation, by definition. Fields with no type annotation are not dataclass fields; they're class attributes. Let's break down each of these lines in turn.

```
from dataclasses import *

@dataclass
class Example:
    typed: str = "a"
    nontyped = "nt_value"
```

This is a dataclass with one field called `typed` and a class attribute called `nontyped`. We can confirm this with some introspection.

```
print(len(fields(Example))) # Prints 1, not 2.
```

Now let's see what happened with your experiments.

```
ex = Example()
ex2 = Example()
```

We have two instances of our dataclass. Neither was given any constructor arguments, so both were initialized with `typed` being equal to the default value of `'a'`.

```
print(ex)
# Example(typed='a')
```

We print out the value of the dataclass. The default `__repr__` on a dataclass prints out all of its fields, so we get the one field. `nontyped` is, again, not a dataclass field and not subject to inclusion.

```
print(ex.nontyped)
# nt_value
```

Here's where things get interesting. Python's rules for looking up variables are a bit complicated (I wrote up a [lengthy paper](https://gist.github.com/Mercerenies/df8fb4243d39f45615e1a7d10a66f011) on the topic, just to have the full description in one place). First, Python looks for `nontyped` on the instance's `__dict__`. `ex.__dict__` only has one field: `typed`. This was set in its dataclass-generated constructor. There is no `nontyped` field on the instance. So Python falls back to looking on the class. There *is* a class variable called `nontyped`, so we use that. If the class variable was a descriptor (i.e. if it had defined `__get__`), then we would call that, which is what happens for `@property`s and instance methods. But the value of the variable is a string, not a descriptor, so we return it verbatim.

```
print(asdict(ex))
# {'typed': 'a'}
```

`asdict` is defined by the `dataclasses` library and returns a dictionary of the dataclass fields. Again, `nontyped` is *not* a dataclass field, so it is excluded.

```
ex.nontyped = 'new_value'
print(ex.nontyped)
# new_value
```

This does *not* modify the class variable. We've assigned to a value on an instance. If our class variable had been a descriptor (like a `@property`), we would have called `__set__` on it. But it isn't, so we instead create a new entry in `ex.__dict__` and set it there. Note that this will *not* show up in `asdict(ex)` which, again, only considers dataclass fields. But at this point, `ex.__dict__` has two fields on it.

```
print(ex2.nontyped)
# nt_value
```

We did not modify the class variable (only an instance variable on `__dict__` that happens to share a name). So this prints out the original value of the class variable.

```
print(asdict(ex))
# {'typed': 'a'}

print(asdict(ex2))
# {'typed': 'a'}
```

Again, there is only one dataclass field. Adding new values to `__dict__` by hand does not change the properties of the dataclass.

So everything you're seeing is all just a consequence of Python's variable lookup rules, not a consequence of dataclasses specifically.